# replacement for na.locf.xts (extremely slow when used with a multicolumn xts)

Tags: r, loops, xts

The R function

> xts:::na.locf.xts

is extremely slow when used with a multicolumn xts of more than a few columns.
There is indeed a loop over the columns in the code of na.locf.xts
I am trying to find a way to avoid this loop.

Any idea?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a loop? Are you one of the many people that (erroneously) think for-loops are slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop in `na.locf.xts` is slow because it creates a copy of the entire object for each column in the object.  The loop itself isn't slow; the copies created by `[.xts` are slow.

There's an experimental (and therefore unexported) version of `na.locf.xts` on R-Forge that moves the loop over columns to C, which avoids copying the object.  It's quite a bit faster for very large objects.

```
set.seed(21)
m <- replicate(20, rnorm(1e6))
is.na(m) <- sample(length(x), 1e5)
x <- xts(m, Sys.time()-1e6:1)
y <- x[1:1e5,1:3]

> # smaller objects
> system.time(a <- na.locf(y))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.008 
> system.time(b <- xts:::.na.locf.xts(y))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.003 
> identical(a,b)
[1] TRUE

> # larger objects
> system.time(a <- na.locf(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.620   1.420   3.064 
> system.time(b <- xts:::.na.locf.xts(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.124   0.092   0.220 
> identical(a,b)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: for reference, this is the link to the experimental version of na.locf.xts https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/xts/R/na.R?view=markup&revision=793&root=xts

Answer (score 1):

```
timeIndex <- index(x)
x <- apply(x, 2, na.locf)
x <- as.xts(x, order.by = timeIndex)
```

This avoids the column-by-column data copying.  Without this, when filling the nth column, you make a copy of 1 : (n - 1) columns and append the nth column to it, which becomes prohibitively slow when n is large.